# Changing the "Sign-up fee" text in Woocommerce Subscriptions causes http 500 error

Tags: woocommerce, webhooks, subscriptions

I am new here and can see another question for what i am asking but i need to ask more questions regarding the answer but because i dont have enough reputation points, I am unable to ask.

But i am trying to insert the below code into the `woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string` filter located in `class-wc-subscriptions-product.php` in the function `get_price_string()`

But I dont know EXACTLY where to insert this code, can someone help? maybe tell me the line number where this should be inserted?

```
    function change_subscription_product_string( $subscription_string, $product, $include )
{
    if( $include['sign_up_fee'] ){
        $subscription_string = str_replace('sign-up fee', 'Hardware cost', $subscription_string);
    }
    return $subscription_string;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string', 'change_subscription_product_string', 10, 3 );
```